# Condition based on column created after partition SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, partition

I used over partition to create a table with SalespersonID, AvgLineProfit, AvgLineProfitPerSalesPerson.

```
select distinct
    invoices.SalespersonPersonID,
    sum(invoicelines.Quantity) over(partition by invoices.SalespersonPersonID) as QuantityPerSalesPerson,
    avg(invoicelines.LineProfit) over() as AvgLineProfit,
    avg(invoicelines.LineProfit) over(partition by invoices.SalespersonPersonID) as AvgProfitPerSalesPerson
from Sales.InvoiceLines as invoicelines
join Sales.Invoices as invoices on invoicelines.InvoiceID = invoices.InvoiceID
order by invoices.SalespersonPersonID
```

Now I want to add another column with the SalesPersonID if AvgLineProfitPerSalesPerson > AvgLineProfit, or NULL if not.

How can I use the created columns in my condition?

I tried creating new select query or using 'case when'

```
case when AvgProfitPerSalesPerson > AvgLineProfit then SalespersonPersonID over() as new_column
```

but it doesn't work.

Here is how the output looks like

| SalespersonPersonID | AvgLinesProfit | AvgProfitPerSalesPerson |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 20 | 22 |
| 2 | 20 | 23 |
| 3 | 20 | 19 |
| 4 | 20 | 19 |

Answer (score 1):

You can't refer to aliases in the same select. so you have to repeate the whole thing:

```sql
select ...
, case when avg(invoicelines.LineProfit) over(partition by invoices.SalespersonPersonID) > avg(invoicelines.LineProfit) over() then SalespersonPersonID end as new_column
```

or wrap your original select in a subquery then it works:

```
select *, case when case when AvgProfitPerSalesPerson > AvgLineProfit...
from (
select distinct
    invoices.SalespersonPersonID,
    sum(invoicelines.Quantity) over(partition by invoices.SalespersonPersonID) as QuantityPerSalesPerson,
    avg(invoicelines.LineProfit) over() as AvgLineProfit,
    avg(invoicelines.LineProfit) over(partition by invoices.SalespersonPersonID) as AvgProfitPerSalesPerson
from Sales.InvoiceLines as invoicelines
join Sales.Invoices as invoices on invoicelines.InvoiceID = invoices.InvoiceID
) x
order by SalespersonPersonID
```

Comment: Unfortunately both solutions don't work. The first gives an error: Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'case'. The second: Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'from'

Comment: I hope you noticed that i wrote "..." so it's not complete SQL but just giving you ideas on how to solve it :)

Comment: But I now found the solution, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

In this way it works

```
select 
new_table.SalespersonPersonID,
new_table.QuantityPerSalesPerson,
new_table.AvgLineProfit,
new_table.AvgProfitPerSalesPerson,
case when new_table.AvgProfitPerSalesPerson > new_table.AvgLineProfit then new_table.SalespersonPersonID
end as succesfull_salesperson
from
(select distinct
    invoices.SalespersonPersonID,
    sum(invoicelines.Quantity) over(partition by invoices.SalespersonPersonID) as QuantityPerSalesPerson,
    avg(invoicelines.LineProfit) over() as AvgLineProfit,
    avg(invoicelines.LineProfit) over(partition by invoices.SalespersonPersonID) as AvgProfitPerSalesPerson
from Sales.InvoiceLines as invoicelines
join Sales.Invoices as invoices on invoicelines.InvoiceID = invoices.InvoiceID) as new_table
order by SalespersonPersonID
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).